# Angular nesting dumb component inside a component and show only to a specific page or parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, components

I am working with an **Ionic 3 app** and I have 2 **Dumb or presentation components**. The first **component** is the `<ion-navbar>` **component** and inside it is another component `<header-wallet-badge></header-wallet-badge>`

The thing is I don't need my `<header-wallet-badge>` component to all my parent **component** or **pages**. I pass an `input decorator` to the **navbar** dynamically to display the title of the **page** and I only use *ngIf for the title of the page to the `<header-wallet-badge></header-wallet-badge>`. Something look like this below.

```
<ion-navbar class="bg-gradient">
    <ion-title>{{ titlePage }}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="app-svg-menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <header-wallet-badge *ngIf="titlePage!='Settings'"></header-wallet-badge>
  </ion-navbar>
```

Is this a bad practice? or am I doing it wrong. This question has no errors. I have already implemented `<header-wallet-badge></header-wallet-badge>` to all my **navbar** before I go to do the `if else` statement.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question just whether this is bad practice? or is there some part of it that isn't working? If the former, It looks fine. If the latter, could you elaborate on the issue you see?

Comment: Yes. I haven't yet implemented yet. But I think it will work but is this a fine architecture style or the right way to structure my app? @DeborahK

Comment: That's a very small snippet of code and a very big question. :-) But it looks fine to me so far. Do you have some ionic sample apps that you are using for examples?

Comment: I'm not really familiar to smart and dumb components. I'm just new to it. It provides a cleaner structure to my app. This is my first try in doing it. So I don't have to go all over the place and refactor some code when needed. I just want to do it in the right way and making it sure.

Comment: This may help: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

Comment: @DeborahK just read that yesterday it was awesome. I just want to dive in more when some complex components happen. But I will just ask it here if there's one that I can't figure out.

Comment: I am still puzzled by what you are trying to accomplish? so "titlePage" looks like a var that will live in the page's component right? so if you change pages you also "change" ion-navbar why would you need something what you are doing?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko **titlePage** is just a `input` decorator that I passed in to the child component or dumb component. Something like this:

`<header-navigation-bar [titlePage]="'Open Jobs'"></header-navigation-bar>`

Comment: I see that - but q is WHY?:) what UX you are trying to build?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I'm just asking this if it is a good practice or not. I am just new to components in ionic but I achieved what I have done :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the `titlePage` But why don't you use `this.router.url`?
If `titlePage` is can be changed after day, I think `this.router.url` is more suitable.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
public currentUrl = '';
constructor(private router:Router) { ... }

ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url; /// this will give you current url
}
```

Comment: Router doesn't support Ionic 3 yet as far as I know.

Comment: Hmm, How about using `this.navCtrl.getActive` for Ionic 3?  like this `let activeView = this.navCtrl.getActive(); if (activeView.component == SettingComponent) { }`

Comment: Yes I can do that. So is that an alternative way to use better than the `*ngIf` statement? If yes. Can you give a full example.